# How to use HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API with Angular and Jsonp?

Tags: angular, jsonp, geocoding, here-api, here-autocomplete

When I call the  HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API endpoint :

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json
?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&query=Pariser+1+Berl
&beginHighlight=<b>
&endHighlight=</b>
```

as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/example-location-id.html) using jsonp (because of CORS error), I get a kinda weird error :

[Console Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm5fH.png)

`"Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."`

```
"message: "Http failure response for https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=23 Rue de &beginHighlight=<b>&endHighlight=</b>&apiKey=****&callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error"
```

Although this is a 200 OK:

[Network Tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHNHN.png)

[Response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT44U.png)

Here is my service :

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  public getSuggestions(query: string): Observable<Suggestion[]> {
    const options = 'beginHighlight=<b>&endHighlight=</b>';
    const url = `${environment.hereDevelopper.suggestionAPIURL}?query=${query}&${options}&apiKey=${environment.hereDevelopper.key}`;

    return this.http.jsonp<Suggestion[]>(url, 'callback').pipe(map(suggestions => suggestions));
  }
}
```

So my question is any ideas or "suggestions"?

Answer (score 0):

so I ended up not using Jsonp.

```js
public getSuggestions(query: string): Observable<Suggestion[]> {
    const options = 'beginHighlight=<b>&endHighlight=</b>';
    const url = `${environment.hereDevelopper.suggestionAPIURL}?query=${query}&${options}&apiKey=${environment.hereDevelopper.key}`;

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(suggestions => {
          observer.next(suggestions.suggestions);
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(err => observer.error(err));
    });
  }
```

I just use fetch instead, but if someone has a solution with jsonp, I'm pretty curious.